# Print new line not working in Python

Tags: python

The \n just doesn't seem to work for me when I use it with print. I am using Python 2.7.8. I don't get whats wrong, I think \n with a print should print a new line very straight forwardly.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from collections import OrderedDict
import xmlrpclib
import hawkey

op_name = sys.argv[1]
pkg_name = sys.argv[2]

# Hawkey Configurations
sack = hawkey.Sack()
path = "/home/thejdeep/test_repo/repodata/%s"
repo = hawkey.Repo("test")
repo.repomd_fn = path % "repomd.xml"
repo.primary_fn = path % "b6f6911f7d9fb63f001388f1ecd0766cec060c1d04c703c6a74969eadc24ec97-primary.xml.gz"
repo.filelists_fn = path % "df5897ed6d3f87f2be4432543edf2f58996e5c9e6a7acee054f9dbfe513df4da-filelists.xml.gz"
sack.load_repo(repo,load_filelists=True)

# Main Function
if __name__ == "__main__":
        print "Querying the repository\n"
        print "-----------------------\n"
        print "Found packages :\n"
        print "--------------\n"
        q = hawkey.Query(sack)
        q = q.filter(name=pkg_name,latest_per_arch=True)[0]
        if q:
                for pkg in q:
                        print str(pkg)
        else:
                print "No packages with name "+pkg_name+" found. Exiting"
                sys.exit()
        print "--------------------"
        print "Performing Dependency Check"
```

Output is something like this. Basically its printing in the same line :

Querying the repository ----------------------- Found packages : --------------

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: Is it printing two lines? Post the output.

Comment: Please define *doesn't seem to work*. Add the expected output and the current output

Comment: `print` automatically adds an end line character. So don't add one and you should be good.

Comment: Do you want an additional blank line before the next print statement?

Comment: @vk1011 Either that or just let \n print a new line for me

Comment: what is the os that you are running on? How are you running this?

Comment: Fedora RC21 ...64 bit

Comment: Is this a CGI script or something? How are you viewing it?

Comment: Running this python file from a shell script, new line gets printed if run normally and not from a shell script

Answer (score 0):

Using print method automatically add \n at the end of the line so its not necessary put \n at the end of each line.

Comment: ... if `print` wasn't protected by a trailing comma. E.g. `print "some",; print " other"` gives you exactly one line of output "some  other"

Comment: Hi, I tried just right now in a online compiler and see what happened. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1bgcm8hcig009b/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.png?dl=0

Comment: Running this python file from a shell script, new line gets printed if run normally and not from a shell script